# pandas - Groupby two functions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've been trying to get a cumsum on a pandas groupby object. I need the cumsum to be shifted by one, which is achieved by shift(). However, doing both of these functions on a single groupby object gives some unwanted results:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'B': [2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5]})

df.groupby('A').cumsum().shift()
```

which gives:

```
      B
0   NaN
1   2.0
2   5.0
3  10.0
4   2.0
5   5.0
```

I.e. the last value of the cumsum() on group 1 is shifted into the first value of group 2. What I want is these groups to stay seperated, and to get:

```
      B
0   NaN
1   2.0
2   5.0
3   NaN
4   2.0
5   5.0
```

But I'm not sure how to get both functions to work on the groupby object combined. Can't find this question anywhere else. Have been playing around with agg but can't seem to work that out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lambda function` with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), also is necessary define columns in list after `groupby` for processing:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
print (df)
   A    B
0  1  NaN
1  1  2.0
2  1  5.0
3  2  NaN
4  2  2.0
5  2  5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of your *first* operation `df.groupby('A').cumsum()` is a regular dataframe. It is equivalent to `df.groupby('A')[['B']].cumsum()`, but Pandas conveniently allows you to omit the `[['B']]` indexing part.

Any subsequent operation on this dataframe therefore will not *by default* be performed groupwise, unless you use `GroupBy` *again*:

```
res = df.groupby('A').cumsum().groupby(df['A']).shift()
```

But, as you can see, this repeats the grouping operation and will be inefficient. You can instead define a *single* function which combines `cumsum` and `shift` in the correct order, then apply this function on a single `GroupBy` object. Defining this single function is known as [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), and it's not native to Python. Here are a few alternatives:

#### Define a new named function

This is an explicit and recommended solution:

```
def cum_shift(x):
    return x.cumsum().shift()

res1 = df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(cum_shift)
```

#### Define an anonymous `lambda` function

A one-line version of the above:

```
res2 = df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
```

#### Use a library which composes

This a pure functional solution; for example, via 3rd party [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose):

```
from toolz import compose
from operator import methodcaller

cumsum_shift_comp = compose(methodcaller('shift'), methodcaller('cumsum'))

res3 = df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(cumsum_shift_comp)
```

All the above give the equivalent result:

```
assert res.equals(res1) and res1.equals(res2) and res2.equals(res3)

print(res1)

     B
0  NaN
1  2.0
2  5.0
3  NaN
4  2.0
5  5.0
```